# pairing string with for loop -R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

have a very basic question about pairing strs by for loops. So what I am doing is create a function that return all combination of tow characters. I got the general idea working but had a hard time to make the return as a vector. Here is my code:

```
paste_chars <- function(char_vec) {
    res = c()
            for ( i in 1:length(char_vec)) {
                    for ( j in 1:length(char_vec)){
                            append(res, paste(char_vec[i], char_vec[j], sep = ''))
                            j + 1
                    }
                    i + 1
            }
    return(res)
    }
```

So what I want is char_vec(c('a', 'b', 'c')) return "aa" "ab" "ac" "ba" "bb" "bc" "ca" "cb" "cc" as a vector. I dont know why this function always return NULL so the append function inside the loop is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be using `expand.grid` instead of a for loop:

`apply(expand.grid(x=letters,y=letters)[,c(2,1)],1,function(x)paste0(x,collapse=""))`

Comment: Can also be simplified to `do.call(paste0, expand.grid(x,x))` to avoid the `apply(...,1, paste)`